# Site Navigation / Breadcrumb using ASP.Net Web form and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, breadcrumbs

I am working on a website which have pages arranged in one table with Parent Child Relation. Page depth can go to any level and i want to generate BreadCrumb for the website based on the database. Sample Data and data fields as shown in the Image below.

Basic Table Structure is like
TableName **Web_Pages**

Table Columns 
**( PageID int, PageName Varchar, PageInternalLinkURL Varchar,PageInheritance int)**

**Example of Sample Data in the table**
[image: Example of Table Data]

**Example of BreadCrumb on Page**
[image: Example of BreadCrumb on Page]

I want the Bread crumb for the site navigation to look similar to what is shown in the sample image below.

I tried for weeks but was not able to get it right.

I want to use it with out site map, rather i would like to create it grammatically and link the *PageName* field with the correct Page URL.

I want to do it so that when ever a page is added to CMS Bread crumb is created dynamically which can work with any page depth.

I worked with CTE query which is not working properly. I would appreciate if someone resolve this issue or can point to a complete working example which is similar to mine.

Testing CTE not working

```
SELECT * FROM pg_Pages;
WITH RecursiveTable (PageId, PageInheritance, Level)
AS
(
   --Anchor
    SELECT      tt.PageId,  tt.PageInheritance,  0 AS Level
    FROM pg_Pages AS tt
    WHERE PageInheritance = 0
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive member definition
    SELECT  tt.PageId, tt.PageInheritance, LEVEL + 1
    FROM pg_Pages AS PageId
        INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rt ON
        tt.PageInheritance = rt.PageId
)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveTable
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Right now i am trying to create PageName and Page URl using CTE, I am just testing it if it will work then i can loop through the dataset and create a bread crumb of list(ul) pragmatically.

Comment: I want a Query which can loop through database and loop for page that it inherits from based on the PageID which i will pass to the query.Simple sql query either get the all the data but not in a hierarchical fashion

Comment: What happens if you actually change the last part of your query to SELECT * FROM RecursiveTable WHERE Level = 0? Are you gettnig a specific error? Also, it looks like your Recursive function part is wrong - you need to change the t.PageInheritance to tt.PageInheritance, and the FROM pg_Pages AS PageId to pg_Pages AS tt

Comment: Doesn't work give error: The multi-part identifier "tt.PageInheritance" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your CTE is wrong - you are almost there but the Recursive Member Definition bit looks wrong.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_Pages;
WITH RecursiveTable (PageId, PageInheritance, Level)
AS
(
   --Anchor
    SELECT      tt.PageId,  tt.PageInheritance,  0 AS Level
    FROM pg_Pages AS tt
    WHERE PageInheritance = 0
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive member definition
    SELECT  tt.PageId, tt.PageInheritance, Level + 1
    FROM pg_Pages AS tt
        INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rt ON
        tt.PageInheritance = rt.PageId
)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveTable
--SELECT * FROM RecursiveTable WHERE Level = 0
```

In your original attempt, your alias for pg_Pages needs to be tt (and you need to prefix PageInheritance with tt too).

Otherwise, it looks fine.

EDIT

For your additional question, you can just add the additional columns:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_Pages;
WITH RecursiveTable (PageId, PageName, PageInternalLink, PageInternalLinkUrl, PageInheritance, Level)
AS
(
   --Anchor
    SELECT      tt.PageId,  tt.PageName, tt.PageInternalLink, tt.PageInternalLinkUrl, tt.PageInheritance,  0 AS Level
    FROM pg_Pages AS tt
    WHERE PageInheritance = 0
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive member definition
    SELECT  tt.PageId,  tt.PageName, tt.PageInternalLink, tt.PageInternalLinkUrl, tt.PageInheritance, Level + 1
    FROM pg_Pages AS tt
        INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rt ON
        tt.PageInheritance = rt.PageId
)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveTable
--SELECT * FROM RecursiveTable WHERE Level = 0
```

FURTHER EDIT:

Okay, to do what you want, you can turn the query around; provided you know the page id:

```
DECLARE @PageId int
SET @PageId = 39;
WITH RecursiveTable (PageId, PageName, PageInternalLink, PageInternalLinkUrl, PageInheritance, Level)
AS(
   --Anchor
    SELECT      tt.PageId,  tt.PageName, tt.PageInternalLink, tt.PageInternalLinkUrl, tt.PageInheritance,  0 AS Level
    FROM TestPage AS tt
    WHERE PageId = @PageId
    UNION ALL
   --Recursion
    SELECT tt.PageId,  tt.PageName, tt.PageInternalLink, tt.PageInternalLinkUrl, tt.PageInheritance, Level + 1
    FROM TestPage AS tt
    INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rt ON rt.PageInheritance = tt.PageId
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveTable ORDER BY Level DESC
```

What we do here is start off at the page you are on, then work backwards through the table looking for all parents. In this instance, the record with the highest level is the ultimate parent, so we order by level in descending order to reflect this.

Comment: I noticed that even before but it didnt work either But you query is working

Comment: How can i alter this to show me the PageName, PageId, PageInternalLinkURL and PageInheritance. I would appreciate your help meanwhile i will also try. as i have not worked with CTE queries in past

Comment: This show tow results one with all teh data from table and other with the fields mentioned in the CTE query

Comment: Thanks, Query it getting the data with the additional fields but How can i modify it to get the data so that i can generate the bread crumb for pageid=39 for this it should get me 3 rows in following order as Row1('28' 'Writers' 'writers.aspx')
Row2('37' 'Child Page One' 'Pages.aspx')
Row3('39' 'C C One' 'Pages.aspx') I tried to add following to end of query SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveTable WHERE PageId = 39 but it only gets me data for pageid 39 (with only one row)

Comment: I appreciate you replies unfortunately it is not looping through the table to get all the records for particular ID as i mentioned in my last comment

Comment: Are you sure the last query doesn't work? I tested it on your data ;-)

Comment: Query is working but it is not getting me the right data suppose i want Hierarchical data for pageID = 39 for that it should get me 3 rows as Row1('28' 'Writers' 'writers.aspx') Row2('37' 'Child Page One' 'Pages.aspx') Row3('39' 'C C One' 'Pages.aspx')

Comment: It returns 3 rows for me - what are you seeing?

Comment: You are a star.. It is working exactly the way i want... Great Job and i appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retrieve the breadcrumb for pageId 39, you may want to try something like this :

```
declare @pageId int

set @pageId=39;
WITH RecursiveTable (PageId,PageName, PageInheritance,PageInternalLinkURL, Level)
AS
(
   --Anchor
    SELECT      tt.PageId,tt.PageName,  tt.PageInheritance,tt.PageInternalLinkURL,  0 AS Level
    FROM pg_pages AS tt
    WHERE PageID = @pageId
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive member definition
    SELECT  tt.PageId,tt.PageName,  tt.PageInheritance,tt.PageInternalLinkURL, Level + 1
    FROM pg_pages AS tt
        INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rt ON
        rt.PageInheritance = tt.PageId
)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveTable
```